# Как выбрать нужные столбцы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как сделать так чтобы переменной "X" я мог присвоить конкретные столбцы, как сделал с переменной "Y". При попытках так сделать почему-то выдает список строк с 1 по n а не данные столбцов.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None 
names = ['sepal length','sepal width','petal length','petal   width','class']
dataframe = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data", names = names)
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 

dataframe['class'].replace("Iris-setosa",1,inplace= True)
dataframe['class'].replace("Iris-virginica",2,inplace = True)
dataframe['class'].replace("Iris-versicolor",3,inplace=True)

X = dataframe[1:3] 
Y = dataframe["class"]

X.head()
Out[90]:
sepal length    sepal width petal length    petal width class
1   4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 1
2   4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dataframe[1:3]` - выведет **строки** с индексами: `1:3`

```
In [8]: dataframe[1:3]
Out[8]:
   sepal length  sepal width  petal length  petal   width        class
1           4.9          3.0           1.4            0.2  Iris-setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3            0.2  Iris-setosa
```

`dataframe.iloc[:, 1:3]` - показать столбцы с индексами от `1` до `2`:

```
In [9]: dataframe.iloc[:, 1:3]
Out[9]:
     sepal width  petal length
0            3.5           1.4
1            3.0           1.4
2            3.2           1.3
3            3.1           1.5
4            3.6           1.4
5            3.9           1.7
6            3.4           1.4
7            3.4           1.5
8            2.9           1.4
9            3.1           1.5
..           ...           ...
140          3.1           5.6
141          3.1           5.1
142          2.7           5.1
143          3.2           5.9
144          3.3           5.7
145          3.0           5.2
146          2.5           5.0
147          3.0           5.2
148          3.4           5.4
149          3.0           5.1

[150 rows x 2 columns]
```

`dataframe.iloc[:, 1:3]` - показать столбцы с индексами от `1` до `3`:

```
In [10]: dataframe.iloc[:, 1:4]
Out[10]:
     sepal width  petal length  petal   width
0            3.5           1.4            0.2
1            3.0           1.4            0.2
2            3.2           1.3            0.2
3            3.1           1.5            0.2
4            3.6           1.4            0.2
5            3.9           1.7            0.4
6            3.4           1.4            0.3
7            3.4           1.5            0.2
8            2.9           1.4            0.2
9            3.1           1.5            0.1
..           ...           ...            ...
140          3.1           5.6            2.4
141          3.1           5.1            2.3
142          2.7           5.1            1.9
143          3.2           5.9            2.3
144          3.3           5.7            2.5
145          3.0           5.2            2.3
146          2.5           5.0            1.9
147          3.0           5.2            2.0
148          3.4           5.4            2.3
149          3.0           5.1            1.8

[150 rows x 3 columns]
```